# Dotfiles - how to create a dotfile for Visual Studio Code that builds on the current configuration

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, dotfiles

I recently came across the idea of Dotfiles and it is very appealing. But most tutorials / articles explain Dotfiles and then present their own dotfiles.

I would like to capture the settings of my various installed programs with all the modifications that I have made over the years and that I do not remember.

So, to begin with Visual Studio Code (VS Code).

- `/Users/smalani/Library/Application Support/Code/User` this directory appears have a number of files that capture the configuration. I am not sure exactly which ones I should copy and move to a dotfile setting and how I should capture these in an actionable dotfile
- I also searched and found that this command `code --list-extensions | xargs -L 1 echo code --install-extension` creates an actionable output to be included in a dot file

Would be great, if you could help me

- completely capture the configuration of current VS Code setup and
- create a dotfile that I can run on another Mac to replicate VS Code configuration.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you limit your question to fish or Vscode only? Those are two different softwares. Also explain what you've done/attempt to slove your query, it'll enrich your question.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I will do that shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The [CodeSync extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golf1052.code-sync) syncs all relevant configuration data to a user-specified directory, so use a subdirectory of your dotfile repository etc. .